# Anyone ever have a case where unistd.h cannot be found on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, gcc, unistd.h

I'm having a wicked time trying to find a bug in my system. It's literally 
driving me mad.

System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, gcc&g++ 4.9, 5.3 5.4 available.

Essentially I was trying to compile some code for point cloud registration, I didn't update my machine, I started see that Boost for some reason had disabled threading, generating multiple errors that no threading libraries could be found. I back tracked everything to a section of the boost header looking at GLib definitions, I checked and it seems my compilers cannot see unistd.h in gcc or g++.
I checked the files and everything is there, but literally cannot be seen.
I tried using the -I flag to get the compilers to look in the directory.

Example c code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd1;
    char buf[128];
    fd1 = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    if (fd1 == -1) {
        perror("File cannot be opened");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    scanf("%127s", buf);
    write(fd1, buf, strlen(buf));
    close(fd1);
    return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile using the command `g++ test_unistd.cpp -o main`, then I get

```
/home/user/test_unistd.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/user/test_unistd.cpp:20:32: error: ‘write’ was not declared in this scope
     write(fd1, buf, strlen(buf));
                                ^
/home/user/test_unistd.cpp:22:14: error: ‘close’ was not declared in this scope
     close(fd1);
```

All the files I can see are there, I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: What does `g++ -E test_unistd.cpp -o test_unistd.i` produce?

Comment: The error you got doesn't say that `unistd.h` isn't found, so the header's present on your system. The error says it can't find the `write` and `close` functions.

Comment: By the way, C is not C++... If this is C++ code, you may have issues with the compiler looking for overloads... Casting may be required for the arguments you are passing...

Comment: output from g++ -E test_unistd.cpp -o test_unistd.i   is here https://pastebin.com/Wu1YQvr6

Comment: c++ uses the c preprocessor, in this case no problems of overloading would be a problem. This should work in g++ anyway, the problem is with the fact gcc/g++ cannot see what is inside unistd.h, which defines "write" and "close"

Comment: Why do you have a file at `/usr/local/include/unistd.h`? And what's in there?

Comment: The error messages you present are not associated with the code you present.  The line numbers are wrong.  We appreciate you trying to present a minimal example, but it needs also to be verifiable (this one isn't), and complete (I am left suspecting that this one isn't).

Comment: it's empty ..., how the * did that happen

Comment: OK, then I'd try removing that file.

Comment: Try to enclose all the includes in a statement `extern "C"` in this way: `extern "C" { #include<...> ... }`

Comment: I just copied the contents of /usr/include/unistd.h to /usr/local/include/unistd.h and everything seems to work again. I can finally compile again!

Comment: thanks a million  melpomene, that seems to be working

Comment: @JohnBollinger `/usr/local` is specifically for custom stuff not managed by the package system. Reinstalling glibc will do nothing.

Comment: @EvanO'Keeffe Don't copy `/usr/include/unistd.h`, just delete the file from `/usr/local`.

Comment: @melpomene, yes, I realized after the fact that he was looking at a file in /usr/local.  I deleted my previous comment.  Indeed, my first thought upon realizing it was the same as yours: why does he have a file of that name there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing up what we figured out in the comments:

There was an empty file at `/usr/local/include/unistd.h` on OP's system. `/usr/local` contains unmanaged files (e.g. things you install manually). Compilers check `/usr/local/include` first (before `/usr/include`), so you can use it to override system functionality. But because `/usr/local/include/unistd.h` was empty, including it had no effect (except for preventing the real `unistd.h` from being used).

Solution: Delete `/usr/local/include/unistd.h`. That way the real header at `/usr/include/unistd.h` can be found and used again.